# media queries only work at top

Tags: css, mediawiki

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1336px) {
    .rectangle-box {
       visibility: visible;
      }

   #p-cactions {  
    top: 461px; 
    left: 410px; 
      }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
    .rectangle-box {
       visibility: hidden !important;
      }
    #p-cactions {    
    top: 461px !important; 
    left: 1110px !important; 
      }
}
```

I put these on the top of a css files code and they work but when i put them on the bottom of the code in the css file they dont work at all. Why is my css working in reverse? im using chrome. the css file is main.css for monobook skin in mediawiki. I guess its good i got it to work im just curious.

Comment: At top/bottom of what?

Comment: may be the styles present on top of queries are causing this behavior... style precendence issue

Comment: hashem: explained problem more specifically

Comment: Are `.rectangle-box` or `#p-cactions` specified anywhere else in the css file?

Comment: You need put these code at bottom of your CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already figured out a way to make this all work in main.css in a very predictable way. thanks but i have already solved the problem. I changed @media screen to @media. i placed this at the bottom of the css file and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You must not edit main.css or hack other code code directly! The results are not predictable.

Use the gadgets extension and manage your JS/CSS directly on your wiki. There are [gadget options](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets#Options) to make them top-loaded if needed.

If you want to do more complex things server-side, read the [developing with ResourceLoader doc page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Developing_with_ResourceLoader). It also has advice on media queries and what to top-load.